# grpc issue with Drone Agent - Drone IO 0.8

Tags: drone.io

I am running Drone Server and Drone Agent on the same instance, i am trying to connect with the private ip of the instance.

If I curl the ip with port, I get a proper html page.
But in Drone Agent logs I get this continuously

```
drone-agent_1  | INFO: 2017/10/03 14:02:37 transport: http2Client.notifyError got notified that the client transport was broken unexpected EOF.
```

Since it would be on the same instance, it should work, and drone server should be configured for grpc as well.
2 Docker compose file, one for agent and one for server

```
version: '2'

services:
  drone-agent:
    image: drone/agent:0.8
    command: agent
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - DRONE_SERVER=172.30.1.169:9456
      - DRONE_SECRET=secret
```

Docker Compose Server

version: '2'

```
services:
  drone-server:
    image: drone/drone:0.8
    ports:
      - 9456:8000
      - 8502:9000
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/drone:/var/lib/drone/
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DRONE_OPEN=false
      - DRONE_HOST=https://subdomain.somehost.com:9876/
      - DRONE_BITBUCKET=true
      - DRONE_BITBUCKET_CLIENT=secretc
      - DRONE_BITBUCKET_SECRET=secretb
      - DRONE_SECRET=secret
      - DRONE_ADMIN=user1
```

Comment: Please provide the real value for `DRONE_SERVER=server:port` so that we can confirm you have the correct address and port configured. Also it is unclear if you are using one docker compose file, or two separate compose files.

Comment: Updated the description. I am using two different compose files.
Drone server has the private IP Address of the AWS Instance.
@BradRydzewski

Answer (score 1):

In your example you expose the drone server GRPC endpoint at `8502:9000` but you provide the agent with port `9456`. Providing the agent with the correct port should resolve this issue for you.

```
-DRONE_SERVER=172.30.1.169:9456
+DRONE_SERVER=172.30.1.169:8502
```